# Best Practice when setting UITableView delegate and datasource

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I ran into an issue where the viewDidAppear method was not being called for a UIViewController that contained a UITableView.  In fact the tableView datasource methods were being called immediately after viewWillAppear.  I found that the reason for this was that the tableView delegate and datasource were being set in the viewDidLoad method (tableView reloaddata: was NOT being called).  If I moved those two lines of code to the viewDidAppear method (and added tableView reloaddata:), everything worked properly.  I'm a little bit confused because I normally set view delegates in the viewDidLoad method.

Has anyone ever seen this before?  Is it a symptom of a larger problem?  Also is there a best practice in general for setting the delegate and datasource?

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

viewWillAppear method will be called when the view of a UIViewController is about to display. viewDidAppear method will be called after the view of a UIViewController is displayed.

Both of these methods will be called every time when your viewController is going to display it view(i.e. first time or it is uncovered by some other viewController).

So, in general you should set the delegate into viewDidLoad method.

The behavior which you are observing is  absolutely fine. There is no such symptom of larger problem.